# Cannot Scrap li and put result in dict in BS

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape `li` elements and add results to a dictionary so that my code always get what is inside `li` and finally I'll be creating df from this dictionary.

my code :

```
link = 'https://www.propertyfinder.eg/en/plp/rent/apartment-for-rent-cairo-hay-el-maadi-degla-street-207-3455087.html'
r = requests.get(link , headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
data = {}
data1 = soup.find('ul')
s = [li.get_text(strip=True) for li in data1.select("li")]
data.update(dict(s))
data
```

I got this error :

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 23; 2 is required

To make it clear i want to have a dictionary like this :

```
{'Property type' : 'Apartment',
 'Property size' : '2,368 sqft  /  220 sqm',
 'Bedrooms' : '3',
 'Bathrooms':4
}
```

Comment: `s` should be a list of `(key, value)` tuples. Where are the keys and values in `li.get_text(strip=True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the specific elements that contain the keys and values you want to put into the dictionary. The keys are in the `<span>` elements, and the values are in `<div class="property-facts__value">`.

You can use a dictionary comprehension to create the dictionary directly, instead of using a list comprehension followed by `dict()` and `dict.update()`.

```
data = {li.find('span').get_text(strip=True): li.find('div', class_="property-facts__value").get_text(stripe=True) 
        for li in data1.select("li")}
```